# Partition list of files - looking for zsh specific and portable solution

Tags: shell, zsh

Let's assume I have N files without any pattern in their names.

I would like to partition this list in chunks of 10 files. I came up with the following solution for zsh:

```
files=(*)

nfiles=${#files}

chunk=10

for s in `seq 1 $chunk $nfiles`
   do somecommand $files[$s,$((s+$chunk-1))]
done
```

Is there a better solution for zsh? What about a portable way?

Thanks in advance,

Somebody

Answer (score 2):

The following command should work.

```
find . -type f -maxdepth 1 -print0 | xargs -0 -n10 somecommand
```

Note the use of the `find -print0` option and `xargs -0`. This is so that filenames with whitespaces are processed correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use xargs,

```
$ ls | xargs -n 10 somecommand
```